# Are there any true nouns containing a hyphen in the Spanish language?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

In this [Spanish Wikipedia: about Guion ortográfico](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guion_ortogr%C3%A1fico) I found mentioned

> Separar algunas palabras compuestas.

but there are no examples given.

Are these foreign words or are there proper examples in Spanish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are proper examples in Spanish. They are usually two adjectives that describe a very specific quality of the object (in most cases).

For example:

**Franco-alemán**

**Lógico-matemático**

**Físico-químico**

**Histórico-artístico**

**Cirujano-anestesista**

**anti-Mussolini**

These words are not foreign, as said they describe something specific.

There are some rules as to the usage of the hyphen:

- The compound words with Spanish lexemes are usually written with a hyphen when they maintain their tonic syllable or maintain certain independence: **teórico-práctico**
- It is also used when there are deleted prepositions between words in apposition and when the second word is a noun with a upper case letter: **anti-Otan**
- Words with a prefix that are constructed in apposition are written without the hyphen: **coche bomba**
- To separate a prefix from its base: **re-presentación**
- To represent various words with a desire of a Unitarian presentation, usually used in philosophical texts: Sartre **ser-para-sí, ser-para-otro**
- Code numbers, prefixes or letters: **DC-10**, **Barcelona-92**

[Source](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=guion) for a more complete explanation, (or search for *guión* in the DPD)

Answer (score 6):

[This is the RAE article in the Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=gui%F3n#2).

There are plenty of examples and all the rules to use the hyphen. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @hippietrail I edited but I could not get a valid link that's why I explained how to go there. If someone can get a valid link please edit. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm there didn't seem to be anything tricky. I followed your instructions which led to the URL http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=gui%F3n which I'll edit into your answer for you.

Comment: The other answer already has the information, thank you very much for your help I don't know why i couldn't get the link as usual. Thanks again :D

Comment: @hippietrail I think the link refers to another question guion vs guión and not to the question of hyphenating.

Comment: @bernd_k not at all, if you read the 2nd entry you'll find the information about the use of hyphen.

Comment: @Laura Moyà Alcover You are right, but what is this guion o guión at the beginning, a kind of footnote?

Comment: @bernd_k The beggining is another entry, and it's the definition of the word "guión" and the explanation of why is correct with ortografic accent and without it.

Comment: I can't edit the question, but the following URL will point exactly to section 2 but remove the page's header:  http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=gui%F3n#2